# Create column matrix from a 4d matrix for max value of 4th dimension

Tags: matlab

I have a 4d matrix as such

```
data [lon,lat,lev,time]
```

I want a column matrix of the maximum value for each time. If there are 24 time then the result matrix should have a dimension 1x24.

Comment: Have you tried [`max`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html)? Additional parameters let you select across which dimension it will operate.

Comment: @Hoki, I think that the 4d matrix have more than 24 rows, but OP has  made no effort to ask a unambiguous question.

Comment: Show us a small numerical example. It's unclear on what you want.

Comment: size(data)=258x198x49x25
258-lon
198-lat
49-lev
25-time.        need a column matrix of size 25 which contains the maximum value of the matrix corresponsing to each time.

its a case of 4d matrix so i cannot show visually an example im so sorry.

Comment: D1=squeeze(data(:,:,:,1));
M1=max(max(max(D1)));
The above program gives the max value for time:1,                                i can repeat this to get maximum value for each time but then this will be a tedious job i need the loop program for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to have is

maximum element in 3D matrix for each time, then

```
max(reshape(data, lon*lat*lev, time))
```

This will work.